# Is it safe to use short-circuit OR operator to test if a property of the function parameter (object) was set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it safe to use short-circuit OR operator to test if a property of the function parameter (object) was set?

Also, is there any difference between `|` and `||`? (both work)

And lastly, I understand (think) that it only checks if the left side is **null**, not undefined or anything else - is that right?

*Javascript, jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var testObject = 
  {
    testProperty: "test string 1"
  };

  testFunction(testObject);
}); 

function testFunction(testObject)
{
  var testOutput = testObject.testProperty || "test string 2";

  console.log(testOutput);
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of questions in one. Most (all?) of these questions can be answered simply by simply doing some research.

Comment: A single `|` is a bitwise OR, and should definitely not be used for this.

Comment: Better suggest you to have a look at **JavaScript falsey values** and **boolean coercion**. This will help you understand the language much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it safe to use short-circuit OR operator to test if a property of the function parameter (object) was set?

It's safe to use the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) ***if*** you know what it's doing: It's testing for a *falsey* value. The falsey values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course `false`; everything else is truthy.

So it's safe if the property can't have one of those as a valid value, and not if it can.

So in your case, if `testObject.testProperty` can have a valid value of `""` (for instance), you can't use `||`.

For when you can't use `||`, you have a couple of alternatives:

1. `in`, which checks the object and its prototype(s):

   ```
   var testOutput = 'testProperty' in testObject ? testObject.testProperty : "test string 2";
   ```
2. `hasOwnProperty`, which only checks the object and not its prototype(s):

   ```
   var testOutput = testObject.hasOwnProperty('testProperty') ? testObject.testProperty : "test string 2";
   ```

> Also, is there any difference between `|` and `||`? (both work)

Yes, there's a **huge** difference; and no, `|` does not work for your example code. `|` is the *bitwise* OR operator, which converts its operands into numbers (specifically, 32-bit integers), combines them at the bit level with an OR operation, and converts that back into a JavaScript number, and makes that its result. `undefined | "test string 2"` is `0`, for instance, whereas of course `undefined || "test string 2"` is `"test string 2"`.

> And lastly, I understand (think) that it only checks if the left side is `null`, not `undefined` or anything else - is that right?

No, it's any falsey value. `||`'s logic, glossing over details, is:

1. Evaluate the left-hand side.
2. If the left-hand side is truthy, make that value the result.
3. If the left-hand side is falsey, evaluate the right-hand side and make that the result.

Answer (score 0):

|| will not evaluate the second expression if the first is true while | will always evaluate both expressions